# Are SQL Execution Plans based on Schema or Data or both?

Tags: sql, optimization, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I hope this question is not too obvious...I have already found lots of good information on interpreting execution plans but there is one question I haven't found the answer to.

Is the plan (and more specifically the relative CPU cost) based on the schema only, or also the actual data currently in the database?

I am try to do some analysis of where indexes are needed in my product's database, but am working with my own test system which does not have close to the amount of data a product in the field would have. I am seeing some odd things like the estimated CPU cost actually going slightly UP after adding an index, and am wondering if this is because my data set is so small.

I am using SQL Server 2005 and Management Studio to do the plans

Comment: Is there a database in particular?  They don't all handle things quite the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be based on both Schema and Data.  The Schema tells it what indexes are available, the Data tells it which is better.

The answer can change in small degrees depending on the DBMS you are using (you have not stated), but they all maintain statistics against indexes to know whether an index will help.  If an index breaks 1000 rows into 900 distinct values, it is a good index to use.  If an index only results in 3 different values for 1000 rows, it is not really `selective` so it is not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is 100% cost-based optimizer. Other RDBMS optimizers are usually a mix of cost-based and rules-based, but SQL Server, for better or worse, is entirely cost driven. A rules based optimizer would be one that can say, for example, *the order of the tables in the FROM clause determines the driving table in a  join*. There are no such rules in SQL Server. See [SQL Statement Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190623.aspx):

> The SQL Server query optimizer is a
>   cost-based optimizer. Each possible
>   execution plan has an associated cost
>   in terms of the amount of computing
>   resources used. The query optimizer
>   must analyze the possible plans and
>   choose the one with the lowest
>   estimated cost. Some complex SELECT
>   statements have thousands of possible
>   execution plans. In these cases, the
>   query optimizer does not analyze all
>   possible combinations. Instead, it
>   uses complex algorithms to find an
>   execution plan that has a cost
>   reasonably close to the minimum
>   possible cost.
>
> The SQL Server query optimizer does
>   not choose only the execution plan
>   with the lowest resource cost; it
>   chooses the plan that returns results
>   to the user with a reasonable cost in
>   resources and that returns the results
>   the fastest. For example, processing a
>   query in parallel typically uses more
>   resources than processing it serially,
>   but completes the query faster. The
>   SQL Server optimizer will use a
>   parallel execution plan to return
>   results if the load on the server will
>   not be adversely affected.
>
> The query optimizer relies on
>   distribution statistics when it
>   estimates the resource costs of
>   different methods for extracting
>   information from a table or index.
>   Distribution statistics are kept for
>   columns and indexes. They indicate the
>   selectivity of the values in a
>   particular index or column. For
>   example, in a table representing cars,
>   many cars have the same manufacturer,
>   but each car has a unique vehicle
>   identification number (VIN). An index
>   on the VIN is more selective than an
>   index on the manufacturer. If the
>   index statistics are not current, the
>   query optimizer may not make the best
>   choice for the current state of the
>   table. For more information about
>   keeping index statistics current, see
>   [Using Statistics to Improve Query
>   Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Both schema and data.

It takes the statistics into account when building a query plan, using them to approximate the number of rows returned by each step in the query (as this can have an effect on the performance of different types of joins, etc).

A good example of this is the fact that it doesn't bother to use indexes on very small tables, as performing a table scan is faster in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for all RDBMS systems, but Postgres specifically uses estimated table sizes as part of its efforts to construct query plans.  As an example, if a table has two rows, it may choose a sequential table scan for the portion of the JOIN that uses that table, whereas if it has 10000+ rows, it may choose to use an index or hash scan (if either of those are available.)  Incidentally, it used to be possible to trigger poor query plans in Postgres by joining VIEWs instead of actual tables, since there were no estimated sizes for VIEWs.

Part of how Postgres constructs its query plans depend on tunable parameters in its configuration file.  More information on how Postgres constructs its query plans can be found on the Postgres website.

Comment: VIEWs are generally expanded in the SQL query before planning, which is why there are no statistics needed for them.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, there are many factors that contribute to the final execution plan.  On a basic level, Statistics play a very large role but they are based on the data but not always all of the data.  Statistics are also not always up to date.  When creating or rebuilding an Index, the statistics should be based on a FULL / 100% sample of the data.  However, the sample rate for automatic statistics refreshing is much lower than 100% so it is possible to sample a range that is in fact not representative of much of the data.  Estimated number of rows for the operation also plays a role which can be based on the number of rows in the table or the statistics on a filtered operation. So out-of-date (or incomplete) Statistics can lead the optimizer to choose a less-than-optimal plan just as a few rows in a table can cause it to ignore indexes entirely (which can be more efficient).

As mentioned in another answer, the more unique (i.e. Selective) the data is the more useful the index will be.  But keep in mind that the only guaranteed column to have statistics is the leading (or "left-most" or "first") column of the Index.  SQL Server can, and does, collect statistics for other columns, even some not in any Indexes, but only if AutoCreateStatistics DB option is set (and it is by default).

Also, the existence of Foreign Keys can help the optimizer when those fields are in a query.

But one area not considered in the question is that of the Query itself.  A query, slightly changed but still returning the same results, can have a radically different Execution Plan.  It is also possible to invalidate the use of an Index by using:

```
LIKE '%' + field
```

or wrapping the field in a function, such as:

```
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, -1, field) <  GETDATE()
```

Now, keep in mind that read operations are (ideally) faster with Indexes but DML operations (INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE) are slower (taking more CPU and Disk I/O) as the Indexes need to be maintained.

Lastly, the "estimated" CPU, etc. values for cost are not always to be relied upon.  A better test is to do:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
run query
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

and focus on "logical reads".  If you reduce Logical Reads then you should be improving performance.

You will, in the end, need a set of data that comes somewhat close to what you have in Production in order to performance tune with regards to both Indexes and the Queries themselves.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle specifics:**

The stated cost is actually an estimated execution time, but it is given in a somewhat arcane unit of measure that has to do with estimated time for block reads. It's important to realize that the calculated cost doesn't say much about the runtime anyway, unless each and every estimate made by the optimizer was 100% perfect (which is never the case).

The optimizer uses the schema for a lot of things when deciding what transformations/heuristics can be applied to the query. Some examples of schema things that matter a lot when evaluating xplans:

- Foreign key constraints (can be used for table elimiation)
- Partitioning (exclude entire ranges of data)
- Unique constraints (index unique vs range scans for example)
- Not null constraints (anti-joins are not available with not in() on nullable columns
- Data types (type conversions, specialized date arithmetics)
- Materialized views (for rewriting a query against an aggregate)
- Dimension Hierarchies (to determine functional dependencies)
- Check constraints (the constraint is injected if it lowers cost)
- Index types (b-tree(?), bitmap, joined, function based)
- Column order in index (`a = 1` on {a,b} = range scan, {b,a} = skip scan or FFS)

The core of the estimates comes from using the statistics gathered on actual data (or cooked). Statistics are gathered for tables, columns, indexes, partitions and probably something else too.

The following information is gathered:

- Nr of rows in table/partition
- Average row/col length (important for costing full scans, hash joins, sorts, temp tables)
- Number of nulls in col (is_president = 'Y' is pretty much unique)
- Distinct values in col (last_name is not very unique)
- Min/max value in col   (helps unbounded range conditions like `date > x`)

...to help estimate the nr of expected rows/bytes returned when filtering data. This information is used to determine what access paths and join mechanisms are available and suitable given the actual values from the SQL query compared to the statistics.

On top of all that, there is also the physical row order which affects how "good" or attractive an index become vs a full table scan. For indexes this is called "clustering factor" and is a measure of how much the row order matches the order of the index entries.